Get tags of appended asset browser object with python
I would like to get the tags of an object that I appended through the asset-browser.
I know this is possible with linked objects using:
bpy.context.selected_objects[0].asset_data.tags

but can this also be done with appended ones? Is this kind of "metadata" even transfered somewhere into the blendfile?
Thanks!

It does not seem like it, per the Blender manual.

Append makes a full copy of the data into your blend-file, without keeping any reference to the original one. You can make further edits to your local copy of the data, but changes in the external source file will not be reflected in the referencing file.


Yup AFAIK the link between the actual asset and the appended object are completely severed once appended. You can try using a weak reference like the asset name and parse the library but if anybody or a script renames the object you're screwed. The metadata is only kept on the library data block in the library blend file. An improvement is in the works, you can follow it over on https://devtalk.blender.org/t/asset-embedding-proposal/34484/14 PS : it's always better to copy/paste the textual contents of an image in case it goes missing or for visually impaired people. Cheers

@Gorgious u smart
